# Stack overflow after adding jekyll to the gruntjs setup generated by yeogurt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jekyll, yeoman

I used yeoman yeogurt generator to kickstart my project.
The grunt file generated uses (to the best of my knowledge) include-all and grunt-jit to load the modules.

What I would like to do, is add the building of jekyll to this file. To do this I installed grunt-jekyll. Afterwards I created a simple config file in grunt/config/compile/ and added the following:

```
// Configuration for jekyll task(s)
// Compiles the blog
'use strict';

var taskConfig = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('jekyll', {
        options: {                          // Universal options
            bundleExec: true,
            src : '<%= jekyll %>'
        },
        dist: {                             // Target
            options: {                        // Target options
                dest: '<%= dist %>/blog',
                config: '_config.yml,_config.build.yml'
            }
        }
    });

};

module.exports = taskConfig;
```

After creating this file, I tested if grunt was still working by running "grunt build" and as it turns out, it didn't. I get the following error:

```
Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Going through dist/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks
Fatal error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I have no idea why I get this error, as I did not tell grunt to do anything with jekyll (except load it), so I would not expect anything to have changed. Removing the file makes my grunt setup function without error.

Adding jekyll:dist to grunt/tasks/build.js results in a similar error but in the correct module:

```
Running "jekyll:dist" (jekyll) task
Warning: Maximum call stack size exceeded Use --force to continue.
```

I don't know if it helps, but here is some extra info about my setup:

- node v0.12.2
- grunt: v0.4.5
- grunt-cli: v0.1.13
- using: jade, sass, dashboard
- gruntfile: https://gist.github.com/Boelensman1/95bb3ec7298377c8c4c9
- package.json: https://gist.github.com/Boelensman1/1f0c97a7d7720f9e2be4
- .yo-rc.json: https://gist.github.com/Boelensman1/cef88cb2cb925faa355d
- build.js: https://gist.github.com/Boelensman1/5f55c251648b881e3f2d

I think I made an error in my jekyll config file, but I don't see where. If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this results in a stack overflow, but the problem is that <%= dist %> and <%= jekyll %> are wrong. It should be <%= yeogurt.jekyll %> and <%= yeogurt.dist %>. This is because yeogurt is the configuration object, see line #20 of your gruntfile.